# Python unit testing: make nose show failed assertions values

Tags: python, nose

is it possible to show the assertion values that failed? It shows the traceback and what kind of exception was throw but it would more practical to know which values failed.

Example:

```
assert result.file == file
AssertionError
```

Comment: FYI: `pytest` is doing that out of the box (with small comparisons of strings, lists, and dictionaries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`assert result.file == file, "%s != %s" % (result.file, file,)`

That's why ugly `self.assert<Foo>` methods were introduced in `unittest.TestCase` instead of nice and short asserts: `self.assert<Foo>` methods know how to display failure messages.

By the way, I thought that nose do some black magic so in simple cases

`assert a == b`

should show meaningful error message.

Comment: Thanks, I should be using self.assert. You can let Nose show more info with -d. It will show the type but not the actual value.

Comment: Just noticed why you said they were ugly. Parentheses and no ==...yuck.

Comment: @Pickels Nowadays you can use [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/).  It encourages bare asserts but performs some code analysis to prettify the failure output, so you get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 24):

You should run nosetests -d this will display the values of the objects that fail the compare in assert.

Comment: Nope, it is still "<bla.bla.bla object at 0x1068ad5a0>.uidNumber == 1001" instead of something like "expected 1001, got 1002"

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: define your own function that does the trick:

```
def assert_eq(obt, exp):
    assert obt==exp, "\n*Expected:\n%s\n*Obtained:\n%s" % (exp, obt)
```

You can call it instead of `assert`:

```
assert_eq ( self.data['SQ'].code, "SQ" )
```

And this returns this nice error:

[image: AssertionError]

Comment: Super! I wonder, if you add a third parameter - test description, that is - you don't even need to define a separate method for each simple test, do you? Basically, it'll look like equivalent of Perl's ok() method from Test::More.

Comment: @badbishop The method I described could work for all the tests. But yes, it could be customized by adding a third parameter with the message (could be optional with the default message being the one I described).

Comment: Always shocked by the amount of stuff that is left undone in python

Comment: @RobertMoskal Python is not assuming any behavior for you (like Perl would do like for example when doing `"123" + 4` and get `127` as a result :)